# In Hive, for a managed table changed the location to a non HDFS location, when we drop the table, the data in the external location will be lost?

Tags: hive

In Hive, for a managed table changed the location to a non HDFS location, for example Amazon S3. When we drop the managed table, the data in the external location will be lost?

Comment: Testing it would have take you less time than posting this question and would have given you a definitive answer that relates to your specific use-case and your specific Hive version, with its specific features and bugs. On top of that, you haven't supplied the minimal required information (managed/external table)

Answer (score 0):

The below explanation provides steps to create the scenario (done in cloudera instance).

CREATE TABLE states_internal (state string) LOCATION '/user/demo/states';

1) Create database mytraining;
2) Create internal/managed table in a location in hive warehouse location: It creates the table states_internal poing to the location hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/demo/states.
CREATE TABLE mytraining.states_internal (state string) LOCATION '/user/demo/states';

2) Load the data from local file system
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'file:///home/cloudera/Desktop/Hivedocs/hivedata/states.txt' INTO TABLE myTraining.states_internal;

3)Change the table location from hdfs to local
ALTER TABLE states_internal set LOCATION 'file:///home/cloudera/Desktop/Hivedocs/hivedata/states.txt'

4) Drop the table states_internal. Check it deletes the local file file:///home/cloudera/Desktop/Hivedocs/hivedata/states.txt. The previous file present in the hdfs: hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/demo/states is still present.
DROP TABLE states_internal;